Does the change from max voltage to zero in a capacitor behaves mathematically like a portion of a cos function?
Please forgive me if the question is low IQ but I am trying to understand some electrical engineering. I have the following graph for a Capacitor discharge supplied with a DC voltage which is suddenly turn off:
Voltage discharge on a capacitor graph
Let's suppose that I applied a DC voltage on a capacitor and it is fully charged. When I suddenly switch off the power supply, can it be assumed that the time it takes for the voltage to reach zero, the period can be integrated using a cos function? So, if I know that at V_cap(t=0) = V_in and V_cap(t=t) = 0, can it be written like a portion of a cos func?

Hint 1: try plotting the equations you're given on Desmos or GeoGebra. Hint 2: cosine curves are periodic. Would you expect capacitor to be?

Even though plots of two functions may look similar on some interval, it does not always mean that they share some properties and/or can be interchanged.

Cosine and exponential decay behaviours are quite different, as can be seen from their graphs if plotted. Cosine wave is periodic.
But negative exponential voltage of a capacitor decays to zero asymptotically. There is a half-life depending on time constant $RC,$ but never goes to zero. A segmented portion of the curve may look the same.
Do not compare mere appearances. Qualitatively they are different. ODEs describing their voltage change behaviours are quite different.
$$ V''+\frac{V}{ (RC)^2}==0;~\frac{V'}{V}=\frac{-1}{RC};~ $$
